# Send Redirect is not working for external URL from linux app server but it is working from local system

Tags: java, web, servlets, filter

I am trying to redirect to the external URL using HTTP response object from Filter

Example:
httpResponse.sendRedirect("google.com")

The above redirection is working from the local tomcat run but when I run from client Linux server it is not.

is it related to a proxy setting?

Comment: *"it is not working"* doesn't really say what the problem is. Please add the errors you're seeing, the behavior you're observing as well as what you expect.

Comment: There was no error logs found, As I mentioned Redirect work from local eclipse but not from the server